# While running a batch file from Windows 10 cmd I'm getting an error that a term is not recognised as cmdlet function

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is the exact error on the cmd window.

this is the command I typed to be executed in the cmd

```
F:\Fast R-CNN\Cognitive tool kit\cntk\Scripts\install\windows>install.bat
```

CNTK Binary Install Script

```
F:\Fast : The term 'F:\Fast' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ F:\Fast R-CNN\Cognitive tool kit\cntk\Scripts\install\windows\ps\inst ...
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (F:\Fast:String) [], CommandNotF
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Error during install operation
```

I've tried running as admin, direct clicking, changing the path etc. Kindly tell me a way to run this file. It's a batch file for a series of installations for the Microsoft cognitive tool kit.

Comment: As the path contains spaces (Fast<space>R-CNN) you have to put quotation marks around it.

Comment: That is a powershell error.  Without seeing the exact code you are using we can only guess a million times what is causing it.

Comment: `D:\rive\path>install.bat`?? It's either `"D:\rive\path\install.bat"` or `D:\rive\path>` is the prompt and the command (to be entered) is just `install.bat` - without tying out the prompt again.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to enclose the path in quotes
    `"F:\Fast R-CNN\Cognitive tool kit\cntk\Scripts\install\windows\install.bat"`

Comment: It should be noted that the error message as reported by the querent is a clear indication that xe was executing the batch with PowerShell rather than CMD - which doesn't change the fact that the filename needs to be quoted; just an observation.

Answer (score 0):

use "start" before the filename.
Example:

```
F:\Fast R-CNN\Cognitive tool kit\cntk\Scripts\install\windows>start install.bat
```